# How to combine sumifs with eomonth in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

First, I apologise if this has already been asked, I am a first time poster here. I could not find exacly what I was looking for here, but I do appreciate if you could point me in the direction.

I am trying to extract the sum of all transactions from a service that changed name. I want to present this as monthly values. I have a complete years transactions on a bank account statement that has the following values:

Column A is dates, B is transaction types, C is description texts, D is value, E is balance.

In the same sheet I also have a column row of months starting at L10 and ends at W10. This is where I am trying to display the montly totals from the SUMIFS.

Now I have gotten the yearly total to work with

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(D2:D729,C2:C729,{"*freenow*","*mytaxi*"}))
```

But when I try to combine it with EOMONTH() it fails and I don't quite understand why.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(D2:D729,C2:C729,{"*freenow*","*mytaxi*”})">="&L$11,date,"<="&EOMONTH(L$11,0)))
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't make the effort of replicating your setup, but don't you have a paren problem? Looks like you've closed `SUMIFS` following the text array, and I don't think you meant to. It looks like that means to be a comma? ALSO, could be an artifact of a weird c+p but the second double quote around *mytaxi* is a curly quote character, which won't work in an Excel formula. Try re-typing this from scratch yourself and see if it works: `=SUM(SUMIFS(D2:D729,C2:C729,{"*freenow*","*mytaxi*"},">="&L$11,date,"<="&EOMONTH(L$11,0)))` (again, I make no claims as to the validity of your logic)

Comment: On a bit more reflection, what is that `date`? and do you need to `SUM` the `SUMIFS`?

Comment: Is `date` a range of dates in a different column?

Comment: @AlexM ah, you are right, it should be A1:A729 instead of date. I couldnt get the Sumifs to give me an answer unless i used sum.

Comment: @ScottCraner you are right the date is everything in coloumn A which is a date in DD/MM/YYYY format for each transaction.

Comment: @AlexM, wrapping the sum around the sumifs is necessary when the criteria is an array. You would only get the first value of the array without the sum.

Answer (score 0):

The ranges must be the same size in the SUMIFS and using SUMPRODUCT removes the need for Ctrl-Shift-Enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(D2:D729,C2:C729,{"*freenow*","*mytaxi*"}),A2:A729,">="&L$11,A2:A729,"<="&EOMONTH(L$11,0)))
```

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner, however this gives me a 0 value on all months, again not sure why. Why should I use SumProduct instead of Sum?

Comment: Is the value in L11 a true date?  And I explained in the answer why SUMPRODUCT.